# ADO.NET Data Services in an ASP.NET-MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to add an ADO.NET data service to a vanilla ASP.NET-MVC project.  Does anyone know if these technologies are compatible?

When I Ctrl+f5 the solution and visit the service URL all I get when is the very unhelpful "Request Error ... See server logs" page.  Does the Development Web server even write any logs and if so where?

I guessed that routing may be the problem so I added:-

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{service}.svc/{*pathInfo}");
```

in an attempt to fix this but that doesn't help.

I would rather not create a separate ASP.NET Web project just to host the data service.  Are there other steps to addiing a Data service in an ASP.NET-MVC project that are not common to standard ASP.NET project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you place debugging atribute into service class ?

```
**[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]**  
public class MyDataService : DataService<...>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(IDataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
        // Examples:
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);


        **config.UseVerboseErrors = true;**
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that gave me enough info to resolve the issue.  It just goes to show that at times Rep means nothing, you were at Rep 1 when you answered where mine was 13K.  :)

Comment: The article and the source code may be useful to explore ASP.Net MVC and ADO.Net Data Services combination 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/dd727502.aspx